# I can't use my server name in sql server mgmt studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed sql server mgmt studio 2008 r2. i used default instance (MSSQLSERVER) user name, added current user and used the default windows authentication. but when I logged in, i couldnt even logged unless i use "(local)" as server name. I tried using MSSQLSERVER, SomePCName\MSSQSERVER but still I couldnt log in. I tried enabling those protocols on Configuration manager but still I couldnt log in. Anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: Default instance name is just your SomePCName without MSSQSERVER. SSMS is just a management tool. There is not a single SQL Server or database in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run SQL Server browser service.

It's disabled by default.

Using Configuration Management tool(not ssms), enable the service and set start mode automatic.

Comment: you mean the configuration manager (the one with the red box like a medicinal toolbox)?

Comment: Have a look for details: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1946/overview-of-the-sql-server-browser-service/

Comment: SQL Server browser is not needed here. There must be another problem. What does the "Servername" combo box in mgmt. studio login window show? Are you using the right authentification type?

Answer (score 0):

Below are some points you can check
1) Disconnect your machine from network then on command prompt write following command
SQLCMD - L

The output of this command will be SQL SERVER name installed on your machine. You can use these names to connect.

If you face still the same issue then as my friend mentioned check browser service & SQL Server service whether they are up or not.